# How to deal with angular reactive forms validation becoming outdated

Tags: angular

Imagine I have an angular reactive form which uses an async validator to check for a taken username. Imagine the username is not taken and becomes valid. Then, upon submitting the form, the backend realises the username is now taken.  The form will need to have validation updated, correct? It should now behave as if it was invalid in the first place. How do I go about this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Using the control method `setErrors(errors: ValidationErrors, opts: { emitEvent?: boolean; } = {}): void` is what I needed. [Angular - AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setErrors). You just need to determine which control(s) the response is talking about, find the control, and set its errors.